# Does there exist a non-trivial function that satisfy the following relation?

Tags: functions

I am looking for a function $f$ that satisfy the following relation $f(y+\alpha*f(x,y),y)=\alpha*f(x,y)$, where $\alpha\in [0,1]$. The trivial one that satisfy this relation is $f(x,y)=x-y$. I tried with several other examples, but failed to find another example. Does there exist any non-trivial function that satisfy the above relation?

Comment: Nitpick.  That function may be simple, or easy, or obvious, but it is not "trivial".  "Trivial" has a very specific meaning in mathematics and the function is $f(x,y)=0$ which... now that you mention it, does work.

Comment: @fleablood $f(x,y)=0$ is the trivial solution.

Comment: What is the domain of $f$?

Comment: @roxas3582 $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Comment: Yes, but $x-y$ is also a solution.  But it isn't "trivial".

Answer (score 1):

For general ways to attack such kind of functional equations, take a look at Evan Chen's [Introduction to Functional Equations](https://web.evanchen.cc/handouts/FuncEq-Intro/FuncEq-Intro.pdf) and [Monsters](https://web.evanchen.cc/handouts/Monsters/Monsters.pdf). Introductory, oriented at Math Olympiad competitions, it is quite understandable and thorough (as far as it goes).

First question: Does $f$ have to satisfy your equation for all $\alpha$ (what range of values?) or are you searching for functions that satify the equation for some specific values of $\alpha$?

Next, fool around a bit. What can you deduce for specific $x, y$? Zero, $x = - y$, ...? You have found a solution. Does a multiple of it work? It is a linear combination of $x, y$. Any others?